# unicode-math: Understanding the application of external fonts to math text

Tags: fonts, unicode, unicode-math, math-fonts

For the following usage of [Redacted-Font](https://github.com/christiannaths/Redacted-Font), I would like to understand

1. why I get an error when setting `\setmathfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}` instead of another math font (e.g. `\setmathfont{Cambria Math}`)

> Package unicode-math Error: No main maths font has been set up yet.

2. and why the minus sign can't be uglified even when using all its possible codes, while the positive sign was uglified properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{luacode,fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math,siunitx}

\setmainfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}% Using, for example, Cambria Math fixes the error.

\setmathfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}%
[range = {up , it , bb , bbit , scr , cal , bfcal , frak , tt , sfup ,
    sfit , bfup , bfit , bfscr , bffrak , bfsfup , bfsfit, "002B, "2212, "002D, "2796, "207B, "2796 }]

\begin{document}
        \[\num{-8e-06}~N_e^2 +  {0.072}~N_e - \beta\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your font hasn't  a math table . It can't be used as main math font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for pointing this out. On the other side, why does the uglification of the positive sign work while it doesn't for the minus sign? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: The range option doesn't work for the minus, that is an known, open bug: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/451

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to post that as an answer?